# Gate drive transformer for lower frequency (25 kHz)

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, mosfet-driver, tesla-coil, ferrite

I am doing this half bridge to generate High voltage from 300VDC.(Around >10000Volts for a corona discharge tube to produce ozone)

[image]

I have gone through many application notes for making one GDT for my purpose. I am planning to do this in 25 kHz. But most deign pages are dealing this somewhere above 50 kHz.
So primarily I am looking for design formulas for inductance in this frequency. At above 50 kHz, the suggested inductance is 2 mH. So obviously I have to use more. That means more turns and more leakage. Torroid or E core? So what would be the ideal method to proceed?
Thanks for reading.

NB. My purpose is to make a High voltage corona discharge Tube for ozone generation. example picture here. Any suggestions which can help me is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: *I am looking for design formulas for inductance in this frequency* - what do you mean specifically? Where is the output winding for T2? What inductance are you talking about? What does GDT mean? Not 25Khz" but "25 kHz". What is the 2 mH you refer to? The picture shows a TV line-output-transformer - is this what you are talking about for T2?

Comment: You could probably use the same xfmr design and same core with about 40% more turns on primary and secondary (of thinner wire) and come out okay.

Comment: Andy best me by a few seconds... Again. Your formulas are the same at 25 kHz as for 25 MHz. Calculate how much magnitizing inductance you need to satisfy your gate driver. Then L=Al*n^2. Make sure you don’t saturate the core using Vt=NAB.

Comment: @Andy Aka Sorry for missing details.I am talking about T1, Gate Drive Transformer. T2 is a High voltage transformer like TV LOT (Not fully represented in schematic.) I am talking about the inductance and turns and core of T1 which is for Driving the MOSFET gates. Many application notes about Gate drive transformer suggest primary inductance of T1 around 2-4mH for frequencies above 50khz.My frequency is lower. That is my confusion.

Comment: ozone is toxic. how much power do you want to displace in arcing?  automobile ignition with spark plugs are limited in current by carbon resistance wire can be reduced with copper but use simple 14V to arc gaps with tungsten tips.

Comment: Calculate peak current for 2 mH, 25 kHz and max duty cycle. What peak current do you end up with? Is that within specification?

Comment: @winny Please correct me if I am wrong
Ipk= 12V*20uS/2mH= 0.120 Amps   (SG3525 works on 12 Volts , freq 25Khz so max on time 20uSecs
The SG3525 datasheet says its output can sink and supply 500ma. is that what you mean by "within specifications"?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I am analyzing the technology involved and trying to make a working model. on a rough estimate I think the tube arcs above 10000Volts and dissipating around 1000Watts. Because of the high voltage involved I had not yet measured many parameters. But will do soon.

Comment: @UroBorosTech what winny is talking about is trying to avoid excessive magnetization current - hence \$Δi = \dfrac{V\cdot Δt}{L}\$ = 240 mA pk with L = 1 mH and, it gets higher as frequency lowers (to be avoided to stop core saturation). So, this is all about core saturation in the gate driver primaries.

Comment: Yes, now you are getting somewhere. Now, what core and how many primary turns do you need to achieve that?

Comment: @winny  I will summarize what I have understood so far..
First I will Calculate the Vus of my primary @ 25Khz and 12V it is 240 Volts Usec
Now the Turns minimum to avoid saturation is = Vus/(B*Ae)
240*10(^6)/(2500*10(^4)*.5*10(^-4)   ( Time in seconds, Flux in Tesla, area in m2) My core is B 2500 and .5 cm2 area
This is around 20 Turns in my torroid.

Comment: Now Inductance  Al *N^2 (My core around 2500nH/N^2)
So 2.5uH*20*20 = 1mH is my inductance
Now Peak current is Ipk= 12V*20uS/1mH= 0.240 Amps (The SG3525 datasheet says its output can sink and supply 500ma)
The above is what I have understood so far. Please correct me if I am wrong.
in one previous comment you mentioned "how much magnetizing inductance you need to satisfy your gate driver". What is that actually.
also how does this need to fit into PWM chip? It has got Double ended out with 500mA capacity (SG3525). What is the matching, I  need to look into that part.

Comment: That looks correct to me. Depending on how much Vth and Cgs your MOSFET has, 240 “out of” 500 mA available may be too much due to voltage drop, but you are in the correct ballpark. How much space does those 20 turns occupy in your winding area? What resistance does those 20 turns at your chosen wire diameter equal?

Comment: I plan to use around 27 Gauge wire or may be Ethernet cable wires 3 nos twisted together. In any case I think the winding will be tight. But before practically starting to construct it, I would like to learn the secondary parameters and its calculations also.
My MOSFET is IRFP460, CGS is around 2300pf. What are the parameters I need to take care of here?

Comment: How much space does 20 turns of 27 gauge wire occupy? How much is available? Hard to say. Your gate drive is far more important at the very first ns during turn on where you are not "wasting" your available drive current into the magnitizing inductance, due to Cgs charging and the Miller effect. Simulate or test it if in doubt.

Comment: Any reason why you don't just use a different gate driver that's isolated, or uses a bootstrap?

Comment: Gate drive seems to be simple, once the parameters are correctly tuned (Or I thought So) moreover one similar device I have seen is using Gate drive transformer. So I thought better to stick to it.

Comment: @winny I will test it in hardware.

Comment: Good. Share your findings. Also, when I wrote "first ns during turn", it's probably more tens or perhaps even 100 ns, but you probably got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is just my thought experiment.

Since Arc Impedance is a low negative resistance (NR), the maximum power (MPT) will be transferred when the arc impedance matches the power supply impedance, but that also means 50% loss so that may not be ideal.  It may be a conjugate capacitive conductance of current with a reactor inductive source to make it less lossy.

The conduction voltage also matches the arc path length.  The higher the current density of the arc, the lower the (negative) impedance of the arc.  This is critical in designing an efficient power transfer for a 1kW arc welder or in this case an Ozone generator for non-occupants.

The ionization or Breakdown Voltage (BDV) is much higher than the arc voltage, Varc and also the impedance ratios are mismatched for an HV source to an arc load, so a dual-source approach must be considered.

This could be the parallel inductive coupling of your 300V DC source with a 20kV spark generator just to ignite the arc but not sustain the high current of > 3A.

By raising the arc length the voltage may be increased.

Without design parameters, I cannot go any further but the output inductors must be chosen to sustain the current without saturation with significant RF resonance and arc noise which may enter the microwave band depending on the arc path wavelength and harmonics.  It seems the Caps from the HV inductor create a high-frequency Relaxation Oscillator.

[Here's another approach using a Tesla design](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%203.0000000000000004e-8%2063.79968419005069%2030%20120%2050%0Ag%20240%20304%20240%20336%200%0Ar%20240%20256%20176%20256%200%2010%0AR%20176%20256%20144%20256%200%201%2060%20169.7056274847714%200%200%200.5%0AT%20240%20256%20320%20304%202%205%20100%2010.2245008850564%20-0.10208684275804289%200.999%0Ac%20384%20224%20464%20224%200%202e-8%20-2085.647074583979%0Aw%20320%20304%20320%20336%200%0Aw%20384%20336%20464%20336%200%0Aw%20320%20224%20320%20256%200%0Ag%20320%20336%20320%20368%200%0Aw%20320%20224%20384%20224%202%0Aw%20320%20336%20384%20336%200%0Aw%20464%20224%20464%20256%200%0Aw%20464%20304%20464%20336%200%0Ac%20592%20288%20592%20336%200%201e-11%2019261.794308835346%0Ar%20592%20256%20592%20288%200%200.1%0Ag%20528%20304%20528%20320%200%0AT%20464%20256%20528%20304%202%200.0000316628%2028.28427%20-0.7014623450805473%200.004302760604793399%200.1%0A187%20384%20224%20384%20336%200%201%201000000000%203000%200.1%0Ag%20592%20336%20592%20368%200%0A403%20512%20160%20656%20224%200%2013_64_7_4354_20480_0.1_0_1_5120%0Ax%20250%20247%20314%20250%204%2016%201:100%5Cs5H%0Ax%20125%20217%20178%20220%204%2016%20120Vac%0Ax%20348%20358%20428%20361%204%2016%203kV%5Cs%5Cs1Ohm%0Ax%20493%20150%20723%20153%204%2016%204kHz%5Csrep%5Csrate%5Cs%5Cs7%5CsMHz%5Csresonance%0Ax%20406%20292%20479%20295%204%2016%201:28%5Cs31uH%0Aw%20528%20256%20592%20256%200%0Ax%20620%20302%20756%20305%204%2016%20Arc%5Csimpedance%5Csest.%0A403%20112%20144%20416%20192%200%202_512_7_4354_0.0001_0.0001_0_1_2835.6902212950804%0Ax%20613%20408%20704%20411%204%208%20Ozone%5CsGen%5Cs1kW%5Cs%5CsT.%5CsStewart%0Ao%2017%2064%200%204107%205120%20102.4%200%202%2017%203%0Ao%2013%2064%200%204098%2040960%200.00009765625%200%202%2013%203%0A) with dual transformers and a long high impedance arc with an intermediate Relaxation Gen. using a 3kV spark plug ~ 1.5mm.

Comment: Thanks for helping me on this. But I am afraid as for now the method you suggested is beyond my expertise. I need to learn the basics through the present method and will go for this.later. need more research on my part for that.